# What benefit is provided by divine abilities?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, religions-and-deities

The P2E Archives of Nethys [deity list](https://2e.aonprd.com/Deities.aspx) includes a column for a list of "Ability" scores/boosts associated with each deity.  It isn't mentioned in my copy of the Core Rulebook, so I'm guessing it's tied to an erratum somewhere.  Is there some kind of benefit to player characters (cleric or champion, for example) based on this attribute?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These abilities are the deity-related Divine Abilities. The [Raised by Belief background](https://2e.aonprd.com/Backgrounds.aspx?ID=132) from *God & Magic* that gives them functional meaning:

> Whether in a monastery, a religious household, or just as part of your everyday life, your upbringing was steeped in the traditions of a faith or philosophy. You might remain committed or you may have turned from your childhood creed, but your skills are still founded in your devotion.
>
> Choose two ability boosts. **One boost must be to an ability specified in the Divine Ability entry for your deity**, and one is a free ability boost.